# MongoDB not returning a proper JSON

Tags: json, mongodb

When I run `db.collection.explain().find()`, it gives the following error;

```
The last field in this json object has a double quote problem: `"totalChildMillis" : NumberLong(2)`.
```

When I parse this object, I got an exception saying that `NumberLong(2)` should be double quoted. Is there a way for MongoDB returns a standard JSON object?

```
{  
   "executionStages":{  
      "stage": "SINGLE_SHARD",
      "nReturned": 10000,
      "executionTimeMillis": 3,
      "totalKeysExamined": 0,
      "totalDocsExamined": 10000,
      "totalChildMillis": NumberLong(2)
   }
}
```

**EDIT1**

I am currently using Javascript NodeJS to create a sub-process of a mongo-shell. And send explain command to that process and listen on its output. Once I got the output, I need to parse it to a javascript object by JSON.parse() method. Based on this use case, what is the easier way for me to adapt mongo json extension to be a standard javascript object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs on [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). Basically it comes down to the fact that MongoDB extends JSON to add additional datatypes that JSON does not support. In order to preserve that type information, various tools use either "strict" mode (which confirms to the JSON RFC) or "mongo shell" mode, which uses notations like NumberLong() and ISODate() to represent datatypes and is generally not parseable using a JSON parser.

Depending on what you're doing, you can use `mongoexport` which has an option to output in strict mode. But if you're trying to evaluate the explain plan of a query, I don't think that's going to work unless you insert the explain plan into a temp collection and then mongoexport it out.

Your best bet is to do whatever scripting you're trying to accomplish using a programming language (e.g. Java, Perl, Python, C#, etc.) and one of the corresponding MongoDB drivers. There you'll have much more flexibility and power with how you retrieve and parse data.

Since you mentioned in your edit that you're using Node.js, you can use the [explain](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#explain) option to get the explain output directly from Node without having to spawn a sub-process.

Here's a very basic example:

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  var collection = db.collection('test');
  collection.find({}, {explain:true}).each(function(err, doc) {
    if(doc != null)
      console.dir(doc);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added my use case in the question. Could you have look at and let me know your suggestion?

Comment: Yes I am using Node.js but I didn't use driver. I created a sub-process of mongo-shell in nodejs and listen on its standard output stream. So is there a way for mongo-shell returns standard json output?

Comment: No it is not possible. And like I said, the driver approach is the best approach.